# ROS Package for Arduino DUE and ROS serial communication

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I want to make a serial communication between ROS and Arduino DUE (send some sensor data to ROS), which package should I use for the best?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260227/ros-package-for-arduino-due-and-ros-serial-communication/) by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Google "Ros arduino" -> [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial), [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino)

---

Originally posted by [PickBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26245/pickbot/) with karma: 123 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on 2017-04-25**:
Is it compatible with ARDUINO DUE?

Thank you